# jQuery plugin to show text sequentially

Tags: jquery, plugins, fadein, fadeout

I'm triying to create a plugin that shows elements in screen sequencially, one after another, using FadeIn, FadeOut.

The script is showing my elements at the same time, but I did call on, then, after fadeOut the next, on the callback. I don't know what's happening there.

Foreach element in elements it fadesIn, wait, fadesOut and then pass to the next one.

Any help? Any plugin that already exists to do something like this?

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Surtido/xpvt214o/680614/)

Edited: sorry I forgot to paste the link:

```
(function ($) {

let sentences;
let index;

$.fn.talk = function () {
    sentences = this.find(".sentence");
    index = -1;
    showNextSentence(sentences, index);
};

function showNextSentence() {
    ++index;
    if (index < sentences.length) {
        sentences.eq(index % sentences.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextSentence());
    }

    return null;
}

}(jQuery));

  $('.talk').talk();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
fadeOut(2000, showNextSentence())
```

To

```
fadeOut(2000, showNextSentence)
```

The first version will get invoked immediately , not after the event completes

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mkj7t1zL/)**</kbd>

Comment: Why is that? Can't figure it out

Comment: Because the argument expects a callback function that will be called later not the result of calling your function

Comment: It makes more sense now! Thanks a lot @charlietfl